# SortByColumns / Filter / Search and Yes/No

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula

I'm trying to filter data in PowerApps, then make that filtered data searchable. The filter is a Yes/No column in a SharePoint list.

I have Yes and No items for testing.

This works:

```
SortByColumns(
    Filter(
        Search(
            'Verify Research Requests',Complete_search.Text,"ResearcherAssigned","CallLetters","Status"),
        Not(IsBlank('Researcher Assigned')),'Complete' = false),
     "Title",Descending)
```

Note:

```
'Complete' = false
```

When I set...

```
'Complete' = true
```

I get no results in the search. I've tried 0/1, no luck. I've also tried...

```
Not('Complete' = false)
```

No luck.

Any insights or suggested solutions would be appreciated!

[Canvas app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKns0.png)

Answer (score 0):

And I fixed it shortly after I posted. Renamed the column from Complete? / Complete to Finished. Once I did that, this worked — note the lack of single quotes around the column name:

```
SortByColumns(
    Filter(
        Search(
            'Verify Research Requests',Complete_search.Text,"ResearcherAssigned","CallLetters","Status"),
            Finished = true),
     "Title",Descending)
```